# Typescript Symbol.iterator error for copying array

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'm learning typescript while building a react/redux app.

What should be fairly simple copy of an array with

```
let newPoints = [...state[action.activityId].points, ...action.points]
```

is throwing a typescript error

```
Type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

My definition for `state[action.activityId].points` is an array (even tried) `any[]`.

In my tsconfig,

```
 "target": "es2015",
 "lib"[     
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "es2015.core",
      "es2015.collection",
      "es2015.generator",
      "es2015.iterable",
      "es2015.promise",
      "es2015.proxy",
      "es2015.reflect",
      "es2015.symbol",
      "es2015.symbol.wellknown",
      "esnext",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
]
```

I've also tried target `es6`, but no luck.

Can somebody explain what this error is actually saying and how to resolve it?